# Solve $x+y-2=0$ and $y= x^3$ for $x$ and $y$

Tags: calculus

This is not a full question but needs to be solved to evaluate area using double integral. I need to solve

$$x+y=2$$ 
$$y=x^3$$

If I put $y= x^3$ in first equation I get messy $x+ x^3 -2=0$ to solve to find what $x$ is? How to do it using viable methods from calculus, or any other quick way.

Comment: See [Rational Roots Test](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/rtnlroot.htm) and after finding a factor, you'll attain a quadratic which you use the quadratic formula for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly, $x=1$ satisfies $x^3+x-2=0$

Alternatively, $x^3+x-2=x^3-1+x-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)+(x-1)=\cdots$

the rest $\dfrac{x^3+x-2}{x-1}=0$ is a Quadratic equation, right?

Comment: you don't see any need for editing the question before answering?

Comment: +1 But I think the OP wants to find the solution $x=1$ by using some method.

Comment: @AlexSilva, Please find the edited version

Answer (score 1):

It is generally possible to solve a cubic equation like the one you have, but the general formula is quite messy. However, it is easy to see here, that $x=1$ is a solution. Then we can factor out $x-1$ of the polynomial (by polynomial division) to get:

$$(x-1)(x^2+x+2)=0$$

$x^2+x-2=0$ can be solved with the quadratic formula which gives $x=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}i\lor x=-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}i$. Now for each of the three solutions for $x$, it is easy to find the value of $y$.